# Google Maps Dynamic Marker Icons

Tags: dynamic, google-maps-api-3, google-visualization

I am well aware that google offers  as part of their chart api dynamic marker icons for google maps here:
https://developers.google.com/chart/image/docs/gallery/dynamic_icons

There is just only one small problem, the whole API seems to be deprecated. Plus I would really like to have more variety because not all of the icons offer the same flexibility.

So I found this webpage:
http://mapicons.nicolasmollet.com/numbers-letters/numbers/?style=classic

The icons look nice but they are not dynamic and well my client doesn't seem to like em. So is there a differenct webpage or some other sort of service which offers neat dynamic icons?

Doesn't have to be for google maps. Can be for any purpose just be suitable for maps as well :-)

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What do you mean by "dynamic icon"? The term could be interpreted in several different ways.

Comment: i mean dynamic generated icons, not static. For example, if you want to have icon markers with numbers, instead of creating them one by one, you just use something like:
http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_bubble_text_small_withshadow&chld=bbbr|01|F15524|FFFFFF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I did a project some time ago that does exactly this but its independent of google maps, even though I used it to create dynamic map markers. Here is the whole php function:

```
<?php
    function createImage($number, $color) {

        $blank = "/var/www/rbc/dashboard/images/".$color."-0.png";

        //$image = @imagecreatefrompng($blank);
        $image = LoadPNG($blank);

        // pick color for the text
        $fontcolor = imagecolorallocate($image, 255, 255, 255);

        $font = 2;
        $fontsize = 8;

        $width = imagefontwidth($font) * strlen($number) ;
        $height = imagefontheight($font) ;

        $x = (imagesx($image) - $width) / 2;
        $y = 5;

        //white background
        $backgroundColor = imagecolorallocate ($image, 255, 255, 255);

        //white text
        $textColor = imagecolorallocate($image, 255, 255, 255);

        //  preserves the transparency
        imagesavealpha($image, true);
        imagealphablending($image, false);

        imagestring($image, $font, $x, $y, $number, $textColor);

        // tell the browser that the content is an image
        header('Content-type: image/png');

        // output image to the browser
        imagepng($image);

        // delete the image resource
        imagedestroy($image);
    }

    function LoadPNG($imgname) {
            /* Attempt to open */
            $im = imagecreatefrompng($imgname);

            /* See if it failed */
            if(!$im) {
                    /* Create a blank image */
                    $im  = imagecreatetruecolor(150, 30);
                    $bgc = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);
                    $tc  = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0);

                    imagefilledrectangle($im, 0, 0, 150, 30, $bgc);

                    /* Output an error message */
                    imagestring($im, 1, 5, 5, 'Error loading ' . $imgname, $tc);
            }
            return $im;
    }

    if(!isset($_GET['color'])) {
        $_GET['color'] = "blue";
    }
    if(!isset($_GET['number'])) {
        $_GET['number'] = "99";
    }

    createImage($_GET['number'], $_GET['color']);
?>
```

which you show with `<img src="image.php?color=red&number=2" />`

HTH

Comment: thank you very much, maybe late and my project is already delivered to the client but I might have a use for this later so again thank you very much